# How to obtain generalizations in R package Biwavelet?

Tags: r, biwavelet

I’m preparing a coursework devoted to diversification strategies for stock market. To measure interdependence of national stock markets I use R with Biwavelet package.

While graphs are really good for noticing connections in various periods, scientific work requires numerical results. How can I obtain numbers that will in short generalise the graphs?

The data is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i5Yvufe2IUrx42sW9WR0hKMeCTyNyrSGn-fpenE2obQ/edit?usp=sharing

```
library(biwavelet)

wtc_Modfd <- function (d1, d2, pad = TRUE, dj = 1/12, s0 = 2 * dt, J1 = NULL, 
                       max.scale = NULL, mother = "morlet", param = -1, lag1 = NULL, 
                       sig.level = 0.95, sig.test = 0, nrands = 300, quiet = FALSE) 
{
  mother <- match.arg(tolower(mother), MOTHERS)
  checked <- check.data(y = d1, x1 = d2)
  xaxis <- d1[, 1]
  dt <- checked$y$dt
  t <- checked$y$t
  n <- checked$y$n.obs
  if (is.null(J1)) {
    if (is.null(max.scale)) {
      max.scale <- (n * 0.17) * 2 * dt
    }
    J1 <- round(log2(max.scale/s0)/dj)
  }
  if (is.null(lag1)) {
    d1.ar1 <- arima(d1[, 2], order = c(1, 0, 0),method="ML")$coef[1] # Added method to be ML to avoid error: non-stationary AR part from CSS
    d2.ar1 <- arima(d2[, 2], order = c(1, 0, 0),method="ML")$coef[1] # Added method to be ML to avoid error: non-stationary AR part from CSS
    lag1 <- c(d1.ar1, d2.ar1)
  }
  wt1 <- wt(d = d1, pad = pad, dj = dj, s0 = s0, J1 = J1, max.scale = max.scale, 
            mother = mother, param = param, sig.level = sig.level, 
            sig.test = sig.test, lag1 = lag1[1])
  wt2 <- wt(d = d2, pad = pad, dj = dj, s0 = s0, J1 = J1, max.scale = max.scale, 
            mother = mother, param = param, sig.level = sig.level, 
            sig.test = sig.test, lag1 = lag1[2])
  d1.sigma <- sd(d1[, 2], na.rm = T)
  d2.sigma <- sd(d2[, 2], na.rm = T)
  s.inv <- 1/t(wt1$scale)
  s.inv <- matrix(rep(s.inv, n), nrow = NROW(wt1$wave))
  smooth.wt1 <- smooth.wavelet(s.inv * (abs(wt1$wave)^2), dt, 
                               dj, wt1$scale)
  smooth.wt2 <- smooth.wavelet(s.inv * (abs(wt2$wave)^2), dt, 
                               dj, wt2$scale)
  coi <- pmin(wt1$coi, wt2$coi, na.rm = T)
  CW <- wt1$wave * Conj(wt2$wave)
  CW.corr <- (wt1$wave * Conj(wt2$wave) * max(wt1$period))/matrix(rep(wt1$period, 
                                                                      length(t)), nrow = NROW(wt1$period))
  power <- abs(CW)^2
  power.corr <- (abs(CW)^2 * max.scale)/matrix(rep(wt1$period, 
                                                   length(t)), nrow = NROW(wt1$period))
  smooth.CW <- smooth.wavelet(s.inv * (CW), dt, dj, wt1$scale)
  rsq <- abs(smooth.CW)^2/(smooth.wt1 * smooth.wt2)
  phase <- atan2(Im(CW), Re(CW))
  if (nrands > 0) {
    signif <- wtc.sig(nrands = nrands, lag1 = lag1, dt = dt, 
                      ntimesteps = n, pad = pad, dj = dj, J1 = J1, s0 = s0, 
                      max.scale = max.scale, mother = mother, sig.level = sig.level, 
                      quiet = quiet)
  }
  else {
    signif <- NA
  }
  results <- list(coi = coi, wave = CW, wave.corr = CW.corr, 
                  power = power, power.corr = power.corr, rsq = rsq, phase = phase, 
                  period = wt1$period, scale = wt1$scale, dt = dt, t = t, 
                  xaxis = xaxis, s0 = s0, dj = dj, d1.sigma = d1.sigma, 
                  d2.sigma = d2.sigma, mother = mother, type = "wtc", 
                  signif = signif)
  class(results) <- "biwavelet"
  return(results)
}

US <- read.csv('US.txt', header = FALSE, sep = ",", dec = ".")[c('V3','V5')]
US <- US[which(US['V3'] == '20071025'):nrow(US),]

India <- read.csv('India.txt', header = FALSE, sep = ",", dec = ".")[c('V3','V5')]
India <- India[which(India['V3'] == '20071025'):nrow(India),]

joint <- merge(India, US, by=c('V3'))
joint <- na.omit(joint)

nrands=10 #Number of iterations. Higher is better (>500)

# Define two sets of variables with time stamps
DATE=1:nrow(joint)

WA = cbind(DATE, joint['V5.x'])
WB = cbind(DATE, joint['V5.y'])

# Specify the number of iterations. The more, the better (>1000).  For the
# purpose of this tutorial, we just set it = 10
nrands = 100

#Main calculations
wtc.AB = wtc(WA, WB, nrands = nrands)

# wt1 = wtc_Modfd(WA, WB, nrands = nrands)

# Plotting a graph
par(oma = c(0, 0, 0, 1), mar = c(5, 4, 5, 5) + 0.1)
plot(wtc.AB, plot.phase = T, lty.coi = 1, col.coi = "grey", lwd.coi = 2, 
     lwd.sig = 1, arrow.lwd = 0.03, arrow.len = 0.12, ylab = "Period (days)", xlab = "Time (days)", 
     plot.cb = TRUE, main = "")

# Adding grid lines
n = length(WA[, 1])
abline(v = seq(250, n, 250), h = 1:4, col = "brown", lty = 1, lwd = 1)
# Defining x labels
axis(side = 3, at = c(44,320,596,838,1078,1324,1572,1820,2060,2302,2541,2780,3022,3266,3508), 
     labels = c('2008','2009', '2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015',
                                                  '2016','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021','2022'))
```

As for the result i want a table with average covariation for various periods (4,12,16,32,64,128,256 days) measured for the whole time and particular time spans.

Comment: Please `dput()` some of your data and copy the result into your question. Also could you, add the code you have tried, and provide an example of what you want your output to look like to your question. This will help to understand your issue. Thanks